hello, Which API should I call to obtain the transfer record of a certain token contract address?
Which API should I call to obtain the transfer record of a certain token contract address?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
